# Moving Blog and Changing URL

Tags: categories, tags, list

I'm moving a blog with a decent amount of traffic and some good google juice. I want to try and proactively fix links that will change. How would I loop through all my categories and tags on my current blog and generate a list of all the urls so I can check where they would map to....

Thanks!

Comment: Why would the links change?  Are you changing the domain name?  Are you moving to or from WordPress?  If your just changing hosts or moving to new server no links should change.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my [plugin T5 All URIs](https://gist.github.com/1999696). It prints all current URIs for posts and terms.

From `function print_term_uris()`:

```
    $terms = get_terms(
        get_taxonomies(),
        array (
            'hide_empty' => FALSE,
            'get' => 'all'
        )
    );

    foreach ( $terms as $term )
    {
        print "\n" . get_term_link( $term );
    }
```

But if you keep the same permalink settings your URIs will not change, just the host.